# ros2 add arguments to callback

Tags: ros, ros2, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to add an argument to a ROS2 subscriber callback.

The main objective was to print the name of the topic from inside the callback, so I tried to follow [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/68434/get-topic-name-in-callback/) ROS1 example, but it's not working.

These are the relevant parts of my code

Creation of the subscriber

```
rclcpp::Subscription<std_msgs::msg::Header>::SharedPtr subscriber =  this->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::Header>(
  topic_name, 
  std::bind(&MultiNode::topic_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1, topic_name));
```

Callback implementation

```
void MultiNode::topic_callback(const std_msgs::msg::Header::SharedPtr msg, std::string topic_name)
{
    std::cout<< topic_name<<std::endl;
}
```

I get a very long sequence of errors which boils down to

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘rclcpp::AnySubscriptionCallback<std_msgs::msg::Header_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::set(std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (MultiNode::*)(std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::Header_<std::allocator<void> > >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)>(MultiNode*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)>)’
   any_subscription_callback.set(std::forward<CallbackT>(callback));
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308386/ros2-add-arguments-to-callback/) by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1322 on 2018-11-13

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-11-14**:
See also #q289207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's actually a known bug already.
https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/273

We wrap each callback in a datatype called `AnyCallback`. The problem is as follows:

if you just call:

```
auto fcn = std::bind(callback_func, std::placeholders::_1, topic_name);
```

That `fcn` instance is of type `std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (MultiNode::*)(std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::Header_<std::allocator<void> > >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)>(MultiNode*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)>` and thus has two arguments.
Our custom `AnyCallback` requires though only one argument. So there is no call to wrap the callback with two arguments. That's all just to explain the error message you're getting.

Now, `std::bind` can actually be assigned to any type of `std::function`. Which is maybe weird, but works :)

so you can call what William suggested:

```
std::function<void(const std_msgs::msg::String::SharedPtr msg)> fcn = std::bind(callback_func, std::placeholders::_1, topic_name);
```

And this has correctly set only one argument, even though the second argument is still getting passed into the callback.

---

Originally posted by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) with karma: 643 on 2018-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like there might be a bug in our code that allows for various types of callbacks in our code.

If you do something like this:

```
std::function<void(const std_msgs::msg::String::SharedPtr msg)> bound_callback_func =
  std::bind(callback_func, std::placeholders::_1, topic_name);
```

And then pass that to `create_subscription()` then it seems to work correctly.

But I can also reproduce your issue, do you think you could provide a simple, compilable example in an issue on `rclcpp`?

https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/new

Please make sure that you follow the new issue guidelines.

Another alternative would be to use `lambda` to capture the topic name, for example:

```
auto callback_factory = [](const std::string & a_topic_name) {
  return [a_topic_name](const std_msgs::msg::String::SharedPtr msg) -> void {
    printf("topic_name: %s, data: %s\n", a_topic_name.c_str(), msg->data.c_str());
  };
};
```

And then use it when making each subscription:

```
sub_ = create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>(topic_name, callback_factory("topic1"));
sub_ = create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>(topic_name, callback_factory("topic2"));
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-11-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-09-10**:
https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/583